# How to get all non-object properties of a class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

```
class example
{

    public $one;
    public $two;
    public $object;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->object = new MyObject();
    }

}
```

But

```
$example = new example();
var_dump(get_object_vars($example)); // returns $one,$two,$object
```

How can I get all properties which are not objects?

**UPDATE**:

For those who down voted, I meant recursively!

How can I recursively get all the properties of the `example` and `MyObject`? my intention is to write a code to find the difference between two PHP objects.

Comment: `array_filter` the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$properties = array_keys(array_filter(get_object_vars($example), function($element) {
    return !is_object($element);
}));
```

AND recursive algorithm

```
function getMyObjectVars($obj) {
    $properties = array();
    foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $k => $v) {
        if (is_object($v)) {
            $properties = array_merge($properties, getMyObjectVars($v));
        } else {
            $properties[] = $k;

        }
    }
    return $properties;
}

print_r(getMyObjectVars($example));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(get_object_vars($example) as $prop){
     if(!is_object($prop)){
        echo $prop;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$props = get_object_vars($example);
$nonObjProps = array();
foreach($props as $prop)
{
    if (is_object($prop))
    {
        continue;
    }
    $nonObjProps = $prop;
}
```